# Weight of a refurbished Macbook Air package

Tags: macbook-pro

I want to know how roughly the weight of a refurbished Macbook Air package, I need this as to know how much it will cost me for the international shipping.

Here its [URL](http://store.apple.com/us/product/FD760LL/A/refurbished-133-inch-macbook-air-13ghz-dual-core-intel-core-i5) from Apple Store

Answer (score 2):

So we have :

- MacBook Air 13" : 1.35 Kg
- 45W MagSafe II : [558g](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Apple-MagSafe-Adapter-MacBook-onwards/dp/B008BEYJW2)
- MacBook Air Box :
- Outside delivery cardboard box.

Amazon says their delivery weight (same config) is about [6.4pounds (2.9 kg)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00746YPQI).

Answer (score 0):

Since Apple may or may not ship refurbished product in the same package as new retail product, you have no way of knowing which you will get without asking and even then, the order system may not be precise enough to know which one of several identical models in stock you will eventually get shipped.

The retail packaging is more dense and ships inside a second box with brown cardboard spacers that act to add internal space between the inner white box and shock absorbers.

You also could get a refurbished shipping box that is white, more generic looking and has grey foam to protect the contents and accessory box and this configuration typically does not have a second outer cardboard box unless you are ordering multiple CPU at the same time.